# Read fixed width file using schema from json file in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have fixed width file as below

```
00120181120xyz12341
00220180203abc56792
00320181203pqr25483
```

And a corresponding `JSON` file that specifies the schema:

```json
{"Column":"id","From":"1","To":"3"}
{"Column":"date","From":"4","To":"8"}
{"Column":"name","From":"12","To":"3"}
{"Column":"salary","From":"15","To":"5"}
```

I read the schema file into DataFrame using:

```
SchemaFile = spark.read\
    .format("json")\
    .option("header","true")\
    .json('C:\Temp\schemaFile\schema.json')

SchemaFile.show()
#+------+----+---+
#|Column|From| To|
#+------+----+---+
#|    id|   1|  3|
#|  date|   4|  8|
#|  name|  12|  3|
#|salary|  15|  5|
#+------+----+---+
```

Likewise, I am parsing the fixed width file into a pyspark DataFrame as below:

```
File = spark.read\
    .format("csv")\
    .option("header","false")\
    .load("C:\Temp\samplefile.txt")

File.show()
#+-------------------+
#|                _c0|
#+-------------------+
#|00120181120xyz12341|
#|00220180203abc56792|
#|00320181203pqr25483|
#+-------------------+
```

I can obviously hard code the values for the positions and lengths of each column to get the desired output:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring
data = File.select(
    substring(File._c0,1,3).alias('id'),
    substring(File._c0,4,8).alias('date'),
    substring(File._c0,12,3).alias('name'),
    substring(File._c0,15,5).alias('salary')
)

data.show()
#+---+--------+----+------+
#| id|    date|name|salary|
#+---+--------+----+------+
#|001|20181120| xyz| 12341|
#|002|20180203| abc| 56792|
#|003|20181203| pqr| 25483|
#+---+--------+----+------+
```

But how can I use the `SchemaFile` DataFrame to specify the widths and column names for the lines so that the schema can be applied dynamically (without hard coding) at run time?

Comment: what is your concern ? what have you tried ?

Comment: I want to apply schema over data while reading as run time .not hard coded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here would be to `collect` the contents of `SchemaFile` and loop over its rows to extract the desired data.

First read the schema file as JSON into a DataFrame. Then call collect and map each row to a dictionary:

```
sfDict = map(lambda x: x.asDict(), SchemaFile.collect())
print(sfDict)
#[{'Column': u'id', 'From': u'1', 'To': u'3'},
# {'Column': u'date', 'From': u'4', 'To': u'8'},
# {'Column': u'name', 'From': u'12', 'To': u'3'},
# {'Column': u'salary', 'From': u'15', 'To': u'5'}]
```

Now you can loop over the rows in `sfDict` and use the values to substring your column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring
File.select(
    *[
        substring(
            str='_c0',
            pos=int(row['From']),
            len=int(row['To'])
        ).alias(row['Column']) 
        for row in sfDict
    ]
).show()
#+---+--------+----+------+
#| id|    date|name|salary|
#+---+--------+----+------+
#|001|20181120| xyz| 12341|
#|002|20180203| abc| 56792|
#|003|20181203| pqr| 25483|
#+---+--------+----+------+
```

Note that we have to cast `To` and `From` to integers since they are specified as strings in your `json` file.